# Medians Help (Triangles)

Tags: geometry

Medians line segment AX and BY of triangle ABC are perpendicular at point G. Prove that AB is equal to line segment CG. I'm working on this problem (I've already drawn a diagram) and I'm  stuck, any tips/hints?

Answer (score 3):

Let $CZ$ be the third median of $ABC$.
Consider the right triangle $AGB$ with median $GZ$.

We know that, since $AGB$ is the right triangle, then $Z$ is its circumcenter and $2\times GZ=AB$.

On the other hand, since $G$ is the centroid of triangle $ABC$, $2\times  GZ = GC$.

QED.